# How can I implement wiki to existing app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, wiki

I have an app which is working already.
I'd like to implement wiki system so that community owner can open its wiki, and edit.

I want it something like this.

http://example.com/community/:community_name/wiki

Is there any good gem to make it possible?
I want the one in which only the registered user can edit.

Answer (score 2):

I have used https://github.com/github/gollum before and works well.

Answer (score 1):

A google search for "rails wiki gem" returned this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983453/is-there-a-wiki-gem-for-rails) as top result, you can find a list of gems here https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/wiki_apps

The functionality you describe could be pretty easily built in, just a question os setting up routes and some kind of authorisation/authentication (if you don't have it in your app already).

Comment: I do use devise for authentication and cancan for authority.  So I need to find something that could add in easily with them.

Comment: This looks pretty well suited https://github.com/alno/irwi gollum is git based not used it myself so not sure how its suited for what you want to do.